# How do you integrate the new Google Sign-In on a Xamarin.Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, google-signin

I am attempting to follow [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) on how to add the new Google Sign-In (not the old Google+ Sign-In) to my Xamarin.Android app. For the life of me, I cannot find the correct Google Play Services NuGet package or Xamarin component that supports the new sign-in system.

When I add the following code to the activity, I get "The type or namespace 'GoogleSignInOptions' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?" build error.

```
// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
```

Here are the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices NuGet packages that are include in the project:

```xml
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.AppIndexing" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus" version="27.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
```

Is the new Google Sign-In system not yet supported on Xamarin or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Enable pre-release nugets and search for:

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity 29.0.0-beta1
```

### packages.config:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.1.1.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth" version="29.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity" version="29.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
</packages>
```

### C# version of [Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)

```
SignInButton button = FindViewById<SignInButton> (Resource.Id.sign_in_button);
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder (GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
    .RequestEmail ()
    .Build ();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (this)
    .EnableAutoManage(mLoginFragment, failedHandler)
    .AddApi (Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
    .Build ();
button.Click += delegate {
    signIn();
};
```

Comment: Do you happen to know when these versions will be promoted from beta to production?

Comment: Per the last Cycle6:RS1 notes: Beta – Early January 2016 and Stable – Mid-Late January 2016

Comment: in 2019, It doesn´t work with xamarin android and Visual Studio. Versión `29.0.0-beta1` is not avaliable