# Implementing new Google sign in with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play-services, google-signin

I'm trying to use the new Google sign in api in Xamarin for authentication in my app. I'm following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in). Can anybody tell me how I can acquire this in Xamarin:

```
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642070/3021054), but it still says 'Auth' doesn't exist in this context.

Anyone know what I should do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Auth` can be found in Assembly `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth` version `29.0.0-beta1` add this in to your code `using Android.Gms.Auth.Api;` Also make sure that the package is installed properly...

Comment: I can't seem to find the 29.0.0-beta1 version. I have the 29.0.0 version though...

Comment: Update my nuget packages to 29.0.0 now and works just fine on my end (had slightly older version before - 29.0.0-beta1). Is your Activity/Fragment implementing `GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do I have to download the package anywhere else excpet putting it in the packages.config? It is listed under my packages folder in Xamarin Studio so I think it's installed correclty.

Comment: No, this should do it. Do you see the package name in the references section of your project?

Comment: These are the ones I have. http://i.imgur.com/xnSwDkU.png The Auth one isn't listed it seems.

Comment: Seems good to me. Try reinstalling relevant packages / components. I'm using just the nuget packages (no components)..

Comment: But Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth isn't listed under 'From Packages'. Might that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Editing your packages.config isn't enough, you have to go into References > From Packages, then right click and "Edit References..." and manually add the .dll for the Auth package.

Comment: No longer seems to be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and I fixed it by using @Milen's solution above.

I've install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth` version 120.2.0.2 from NuGet and then I added both `using Android.Gms.Auth.Api;` and `using Android.Gms.Auth;` into my Login activity.